# Check product qty 0 or not code in core files

Tags: magento-1.9, product, out-of-stock

If I add to cart p1 product and if I set 0 qty of p1 product and refresh cart page it throws error message regarding out of stock message so my question is I want to find a code where product qty check in core files.

I also tried in `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/stock/Item.php` file but I could not find. Anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is correct, it is `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item`.

Check the method `checkQuoteItemQty`. Around line 582:

```
if (!$this->getIsInStock()) {
            $result->setHasError(true)
                ->setMessage(Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('This product is currently out of stock.'))
                ->setQuoteMessage(Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('Some of the products are currently out of stock.'))
                ->setQuoteMessageIndex('stock');
            $result->setItemUseOldQty(true);
            return $result;
        }
```

It checks if the product is `in stock` or `out of stock`.

The quantity check is just below it:

```
if (!$this->checkQty($summaryQty) || !$this->checkQty($qty)) {
            $message = Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The requested quantity for "%s" is not available.', $this->getProductName());
            $result->setHasError(true)
                ->setMessage($message)
                ->setQuoteMessage($message)
                ->setQuoteMessageIndex('qty');
            return $result;
        } else {
...
```

Switch to `out of stock` is handled in the `_beforeSave` method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks RiccardoT,Now I can track product qty. thanks a lot once again.

Comment: What is $summaryQty ?  I am confused in $summaryQty and $qty. Please suggest me. Thanks